# Need to share text via applications

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-dialog

I need to share text from my applications via other social applications.I have got a piece of code that is working fine but it shows apps list in dialogue box:

[image]

And I want same feature in this way.May be I need to create views dynamically as per application installed in device.

[image]

Please suggest me how can I achieve this

Comment: Do you want to share your Text with particular application?

Comment: @PiyushGupta no I want to share with every application that is installed in device .

Comment: So you can easily use `Intent.ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I know but it is opening applications list in alert box and I want to show in list view .

Comment: Its should not be alert box. It may be Context Menu. If you need second one make custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will let you find all the apps available for the specified intent:

```
public static ArrayList<Availables> getAvailableAppsForIntent(Intent intent, Context context) {
    ArrayList<Availables> availables = new ArrayList<Availables>();

    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);

    for(ResolveInfo info : infos) {
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = info.activityInfo;
        IntentFilter filter = info.filter;
        if (filter != null && filter.hasAction(intent.getAction())) {

            // This activity resolves my Intent with the filter I'm looking for
            String activityPackageName = activityInfo.packageName;
            String activityName = activityInfo.loadLabel(manager).toString();
            String activityFullName = activityInfo.name;
            Drawable icon = activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
            Availables available = new Availables(activityName, activityFullName, activityPackageName, icon);
            available.setForIntent(intent);
            availables.add(available);
        }
    }

    return availables;
}
```

Availables is just a class i created to store all the informations about the apps but you can manage it however you want.
then you can start the app this way:

```
    Intent intent = available.getForIntent();
    intent.setPackage(available.getAppPackage());
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: would be better. you can do as you wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot .Hopefully it will help:)

Comment: Hi , I am passing   sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); in intent parameter and it is returning not a single application .

Comment: Of course because there are more applications which can resolve the same intent. that methos returns a list of applications not a single one.

Answer (score 0):

hare is button click event use it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.setType("text/plain");
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: I have used same piece of code but it open list in alert box and I don't  want to that.

Comment: I have shared UI what I have to create.

Answer (score 0):

Write code on click of any `View`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject Here");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your Message Here...");
return intent;
```